# Multiplication of matrices with NA values

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

If I have 2 square Matrices with random NA values, for example:

Matrix A:

```
     1  2  3
   1 5  NA 7
   2 NA 3  8
   3 NA 4  5
```

Matrix B:

```
     1  2  3
   1 NA 8  NA
   2 2  5  9
   3 NA 4  3
```

What is the best way to multiply them? Would changing NA values to 0 give a different result of the dot product?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Please show your work (code) to narrow down answers. What have you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

NAs will be ignored:

```
## Dummy matrices
mat1 <- matrix(sample(1:9, 9), 3, 3)
mat2 <- matrix(sample(1:9, 9), 3, 3)

## Adding NAs
mat1[sample(1:9, 4)] <- NA
mat2[sample(1:9, 4)] <- NA

mat1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    9   NA    3
#[2,]    2   NA   NA
#[3,]   NA    1    8

mat2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA   NA    4
#[2,]   NA    9    3
#[3,]   NA    7    1

mat1 * mat2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA   NA   12
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]   NA    7    8

mat1 %*% mat2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

In this case the dot product results in only NAs because there are no operations that does not involve an NA. Different matrices can lead to different results.

Comment: Thanks ...what about the dot product %*%?- it gives back a matrix just with NA values

Comment: This is also expected since every operation of the dot product will involve an NA. In general, R treats NAs logically: if any operation is computed including an NA, the output will be NA.